# ATOP: vmcom / vmlim -> SWP is red

Tags: top, swap, load-average, swapping

in ATOP I'm getting a red alert like this: `vmcom  76.3G | vmlim  49.8G`

This is a value that is attached to the "SWP" (so "SWAP" is meant?)-line.

What does this mean and what can I do against it?

Comment: See [ATOP shows red line vmcom and vmlim. What does it mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60474/32022)

Answer (score 2):

The `atop` man page helps explain what the numbers actually indicate.

> **Memory**
>
> If the committed virtual memory exceeds the limit ('vmcom' and 'vmlim' in the SWP-line), the SWP-line is colored due to overcommitting the system.
>
> **SWP**
>
> Swap occupation and overcommit info.
>
> This line contains the total amount of swap space on disk ('tot') and the amount of free swap space ('free').
>
> Furthermore the committed virtual memory space ('vmcom') and the maximum limit of the committed space ('vmlim', which is by default
> swap size plus 50% of memory size) is shown. The committed space is
> the reserved virtual space for all allocations of private memory space
> for processes. The kernel only verifies whether the committed space
> exceeds the limit if strict overcommit handling is configured
> (vm.overcommit_memory is 2).

https://linux.die.net/man/1/atop

It appears that this warning is nothing critical, but just a warning that memory pressure is getting high: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60474/32022